# Почему не отображается выпадающий список предложений в AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, search, autocomplete

Кто знает почему у autoComplete не отображается выпадающий список предложений ?

- инициализировал
- получил из курсора данные, вставил в ArrayList
- создал ArrayAdapter и передал в него массив данных
- назначил autoComplete адаптер. 
  Всю эту матату реализовал в фрагменте.

  ```
  public class HomeFrag extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, View.OnClickListener {

  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  private DataBase dataBase;

  private AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView;
  private SearchView searchView;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      /** all about Toolbar */
      ((ActivityMain) getActivity()).initToolbar(getString(R.string.app_name),
              getString(R.string.txt_home_screen),
              R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home_screen, container, false);


      return rootView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

      searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search_item));
      searchView.setQueryHint(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
      searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(this);

      View suggestionsView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.action_search_layout, null);
      autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) suggestionsView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

  }           

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
      if (!newText.equals("")) {
          // TODO think about this ???
          searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
          new MyLogs("query: " + newText);
          Cursor cursor = dataBase.searchInDataBaseRU(newText);

          ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
          String desc_ru;

          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {
                  desc_ru = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.LT_COL_DESC_RU));
                  new MyLogs(desc_ru);
                  arrayList.add(desc_ru);
              } while (cursor.moveToNext());

              adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayList);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
              autoTextView.showDropDown();
          } else {
              //TODO fds
              new MyLogs("ничего не найдено");
          }

      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
          case R.id.search_item:
              dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
              dataBase.openDB();
              new MyLogs("dataBase.openDB()");
              break;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

А также `XML-разметка -> R.layout.action_search_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: Под дебагом смотрели? у Вас точно arrayList не пустой?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, arrayList не пустой, я его полностью только-что вывел в Log.